Error in GAMIT/GLOBK Software Installation
When I'm trying to install gamit/globk software it shows this error
"*** Now type 'make test'  to install the library and run tests ***
cp libsofa.a ../../../../libsofa.a
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Failure in make_gamit -- install_software terminated"
Anyone knows the solution please respond. I'm trying to resolve it from 5 days...enter image description here

You've tagged your question as being about Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, which is years beyond it's EOL.   Is that really what you're using?

Only supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is EOL thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 12.04 ESM was in extended support and only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2017/03/15/ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-reaches-end-of-life-on-april-28-2017/

Ubuntu 12 is long out of support. Please consider using a modern LTS release of Ubuntu.
